# Would a Christmas bounty giveaway be appropriate?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I'd like to give out a number of bounties to answers that are underrated, in honor of the Christmas season and the awesome hat awesomeness that is currently going on.

So far I've just been picking questions and answers myself, but it occurs to me that perhaps I could leverage everyone else's eyes and ears.

The format would be something like:

- Nominate answers that are currently underrated - for whatever reason they should be worthy but haven't gotten the votes they deserve.
- You can't nominate your own answer, but you can pick an answer to your own question.
- A user can't win more than once.
- Daily through Jan 6th, I'll pick the highest voted nomination that I haven't already bountied and bounty it under the "exemplary answer" bounty type.  I'll award the bounty as soon as I can.
- The answerer gets the bounty plus the "bounty awarded" hat.

Before I do something like this, my question is, is this acceptable?  I don't want to start something like this without it being reviewed first.  If this idea's no good, I'll think of something else to do to get us in the Christmas spirit :)

Comment: If you go ahead with this, I might just join in on rewarding some winners...

Comment: I love this idea! :) Christmas spirit is never a bad thing. :)

Comment: I have 20k reputation to burn, you don't ;) Feel free to suggest worthy answers.

Comment: Alright then.  Consider this operation *a go.*

Answer (score 5):

I don't see why it *wouldn't* be acceptable. The whole reason for the exemplary answer bounty is to reward the answerer with something extra and to draw attention to it and the question, so (in my opinion) a community-based bounty giveaway would be just as valid as choosing answers yourself.

Comment: There's even an "an answer deserves more reward" option when starting bounties in the first place!

Answer (score 2):

Are you aware of the [low-rep and anonymous feedback mechanism](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98630/anonymous-user-feedback-now-in-testing)? We already track "underrated" answers according to this feedback, you can see it on [this 10k-only page](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tools/post-feedback/underrated?filter=all), so why not use it?

For instance, [the top answer on this list](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35871/what-quest-is-the-object-dravins-bow-from/38115#38115) has zero upvotes but 15 "this was useful" feedback votes.

Comment: TCO of your instance... tomorrow :/

Comment: @badp what's TCO?

Comment: "Taken Care Of"

Comment: 1) I didn't know about that page! 2) @agent86 can't see it just yet!

Comment: Yeah, I'm not *quite* to 10k yet, so I can't see that.  It's probably a good source of fodder though.

Comment: @LessPop Me neither. :( Why isn't there a link from the 10k tools page? I couldn't find one at least.

Comment: @Fallen it's the bottom link in the "stats" tab.